# How do I use scrollIt with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

How do I use [scrollIt](http://www.bytemuse.com/scrollIt.js/) with Meteor?  I know that jQuery is included with Meteor, but do I need to add the reference to scrollIt as well, which you can't do with Meteor right?

**1) Include jQuery and scrollIt.js**

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scrollIt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**2) Put a data-scroll-index attribute on each section**

```
<div data-scroll-index="0">..content..</div>
<div data-scroll-index="1">...</div>
<div data-scroll-index="2">...</div>
```

**3) Put corresponding data-scroll-nav attributes on each nav element**

```
<a data-scroll-nav="0">About</a>
<a data-scroll-nav="1">Usage</a>
<a data-scroll-nav="2">Options</a>
```

**4) For links to sections, put on a data-scroll-goto attribute**

```
<a data-scroll-goto="0">Back to top</a>
```

**5) Call scrollIt()**

```
$(function(){
  $.scrollIt();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of welcome to Stackoverflow. Second I am assuming here, basic understanding of meteor. I will just give html templatecode  and related js code for plugin inside your meteor project

Following the are steps for your your usecase

**Step-1**: Put the your `scroll.js` lib file inside the `client` directory under your project root directory

So, it will be like `<your-project-lib>/client/scrollit.js`

You dont need to include script tags anywhere. Meteor handles it.

**Step-2**: Put the html code inside template like follows-

scrollTemplate.html

```
<template name="scrollTemplate.html">

 <div data-scroll-index="0">..content..</div>
 <div data-scroll-index="1">...</div>
 <div data-scroll-index="2">...</div>

 <~!-- Your whatever html code will go inside here -->
 <a data-scroll-nav="0">About</a>
 <a data-scroll-nav="1">Usage</a>
 <a data-scroll-nav="2">Options</a>
</template>
```

**Step-3**: Initialized the scroll it in `rendered` event of template

```
Template.scrollTemplate.rendered= function(){
   $.scrollIt();
}
```

rendered event for template is like `ready` event but only for html inside template.

I have not tested it but it should work